# What exactly does it mean that the key $e \in \mathcal K$ uniquely determines $E_e$?

Tags: terminology, cryptography

What exactly does it mean that the key $e \in \mathcal K$ **uniquely determines** $E_e$ ?

Does it mean that for each $e \in \mathcal K$ there exist only one function $E_e$ corresponding to $e$ ?

Does this imply that two different keys can correspond to the same function ? I mean, this doesn't violate that there only correspond one function to each key ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that the function $E_e$ as a whole (as a bijective function from the message space $\mathcal{M}$ to the ciphertext space $\mathcal{C}$) is determined by the key $e$ alone. This implies that for every $e \in \mathcal{K}$ and every $m \in \mathcal{M}$ there is a uniquely determined $E_e(m) \in \mathcal{C}$. So yes to your first question.

This doesn't exclude the possibility that two different $e,e'$ can determine the same functions $E_e = E_{e'}$ (although this is unusual to happen in practice). This could happen, and is not in violation with the previous fact.

Comment: But the author Richard A. Mollin then defines a cipher as a set $\{ E_e : e \in \mathcal K \}$ where for each $e \in \mathcal K$ there exist $d \in \mathcal K$ such that $E_e^{-1} = E_d$. He then state that the key $d$ corresponding to $e$ is unique ? But this might not be the case if $E_e = E_{e'}$ for $e \neq e'$ ? Have I misunderstood something ?

Comment: So a cipher is different from an enciphering function?